# Why Normal force is different for inclined plane and inclined road?

Tags: forces, friction, geometry

Check this video till 7:20. I am trying it understand it mathematically.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWXT-IzgbP0

In video he explains the answer to my question.

But this still doesn't explain why math is failing.

By failing I mean, we should get same equation for same diagram. Right?

But here both equations are different for same diagram configuration.

See the equations in green box at 7:20

Any in depth explaination on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagrams are very similar, true, but the resultant acceleration is different.

On the left hand diagram (the narrator calls it 'regular incline'), the acceleration would be down the incline, in the direction of the arrow $F_g$.

On the right hand diagram, 'banked curve', the car accelerates horizontally towards middle of the circle that it's travelling around, in the direction of the arrow $F_{XN}$.